# jq - add element from outside array

Tags: json, jq, aws-cli

```
{
    "TypeName": "AWS:Application",
    "InstanceId": "i-0af68a7cf857bd010",
    "SchemaVersion": "1.1",
    "CaptureTime": "2023-03-01T16:28:43Z",
    "Entries": [
        {
            "ApplicationType": "admin",
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "Name": "accountsservice",
            "PackageId": "accountsservice_0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb",
            "Publisher": "Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>",
            "Summary": "query and manipulate user account information",
            "URL": "https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/AccountsService/",
            "Version": "0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3"
        }
     ]
}
```

This is a snippet of a large selection I'm trying to format to eventually export as csv.

```
.Entries[] | [.ApplicationType, .Name, .Version, .PackageId, .Publisher, .URL, .Summary]
```

```
[
  "admin",
  "accountsservice",
  "0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3",
  "accountsservice_0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb",
  "Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>",
  "https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/AccountsService/",
  "query and manipulate user account information"
]
```

Is there a way that I can insert the .InstanceId from outside the array into the array, leaving me with:

```
[
  "i-0af68a7cf857bd010",
  "admin",
  "accountsservice",
  "0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3",
  "accountsservice_0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb",
  "Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>",
  "https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/AccountsService/",
  "query and manipulate user account information"
]

Thank you so much for the assistance!
```

Comment: Save it in a variable beforehand, and reference it in the array: `.InstanceId as $id | .Entries[] | [$id, .ApplicationType, .Name, …]`

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the arrays of two streams (one stream contains a single array, the other stream contains multiple arrays). This builds the cartesian product of both streams.

```
[.InstanceId] + (.Entries[] | [.ApplicationType, .Name, .Version, .PackageId, .Publisher, .URL, .Summary])
```

Output:

```json
[
  "i-0af68a7cf857bd010",
  "admin",
  "accountsservice",
  "0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3",
  "accountsservice_0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb",
  "Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>",
  "https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/AccountsService/",
  "query and manipulate user account information"
]
```